# Beginner C++ - Trying to catch an exception

Tags: c++, c++11, sqlite

So basically I have this code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#include "libsqlite.hpp"

int main()
{
    sqlite::sqlite db( "firefly.sqlite" );

    auto cur = db.get_statement(); 

    // cur->set_sql( "CREATE TABLE students_mark (sid INT, name VARCHAR(255), pt1_mark INT, pt2_mark INT, cw_mark INT, PRIMARY KEY(sid, name));" );
    cur->set_sql( "INSERT INTO students_mark (sid, name, pt1_mark, pt2_mark, cw_mark) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?);" );

    cur->prepare();
}
```

Which gives me this error:

```
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type sqlite::exception: std::exception
Abort trap: 6
```

So I tried to catch the exception to understand it better, but I can't seem to archieve this goal.

Here's what I did:

```
try {
    cur->prepare();
} catch(exception& e) {
    cout << "Error: " << e.what() << endl;
}
```

and this gives me this output: `Error: std::exception`

What can I do?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Isn't the output `Error: std::exception` generated by your `catch` statement? What is the issue?

Comment: not clear what you want to do. Catching the exceptions seems to work fine

Comment: Are you sure this is your exact code? Did you by any chance do `catch(exception e)` (forgetting the `&`)? Your output doesn't match https://github.com/glycos/libsqlitepp/blob/master/libsqlite.hpp#L37

Comment: Since you get *terminating with uncaught exception of type sqlite::exception:* why not try catching a `sqlite::exception`?

Comment: @NathanOliver I just tried it, it gives me `Error : Sqlite error: Could not prepare sql.`

Comment: OK.  Now research that .

Comment: Then you've caught the exception just fine. If you want to know where and why it was thrown you're going to have to use a debugger.

Comment: @mokiliiiLo Unfortunately, the wrapper library you are using [throws away the error code from sqlite itself](https://github.com/glycos/libsqlitepp/blob/master/libsqlite.hpp#L40). Maybe hack the header to print out the code, then [check in the documentation](https://sqlite.org/rescode.html) what it means?

Comment: @BoBTFish Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately I'm quite new to C++, SO I have no idea on how to do this. Could you please help me ?

Comment: @mokiliiiLo I assume you have copied the library locally somewhere? It is all implemented in that one header. Find the definition of [`prepare`](https://github.com/glycos/libsqlitepp/blob/master/libsqlite.hpp#L75), and add `std::cerr << rc << '\n';` to print out the error code. Or use a debugger and break here to inspect the value of `rc.

Comment: There are [`sqlite3_errcode`, `sqlite3_errmsg` et al](http://sqlite.org/capi3ref.html#sqlite3_errcode) in SQLite API. See if your library exposes them through the wrapper, or lets you obtain a DB handle to call them directly.

Answer (score 1):

Exceptions exist for several reasons. But right now it's there to let you know somethings wrong. Simply catching it won't solve the issue itself. It will only change the behaviour of your program after the problem occurred.

You caught the exception just fine using `catch (sqlite::exception &e)`, now you know what is the issue. Now, research and fix what the exception is telling you.